# Как с помощью gulp вывести селекторы в css файл

Tags: php, css, gulp

Страница выводится с помощью php, как с помощью gulp вывести селекторы в css файл.
Другими словами чтобы создалась заготовка css файла с уже прописанными селекторами 
Php + nodejs - пример разработки на локальном сервере:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
gulp.task('serve', function(){

    browserSync.init({
       //proxy: "http://your_site"
      proxy: {
        target: "http://your_site"
        },
        open: "external",
        host: "your_site",
        port: 3000
    });

    browserSync.watch("**/*.*").on("change", browserSync.reload);
});
```

Comment: А вы можете понятней выражаться?

Comment: Вообщем что бы не искать названия классов, айдишники, теги - а потом каждый заносить в css файл , чтобы запустил плагин , и готов css файл с прописанными селекторами. Только сиди и добавляй свойства в готовую болванку(css файл).

Comment: Вообщем вопрос - есть ли такой плагин, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли такой плагин нужен, т. к.

1. В css-файле мусор не нужен. С такими задачами вполне может справиться IDE.
2. Важен порядок css-селекторов в файле.
3. Селекторы могут быть составными.
4. Php + nodejs - это сомнительный набор.

С другой стороны, не могу исключить, что кто-то всё же что-то такое сделал.

Comment: А где ответ на вопрос? Тут как бы не ваше мнение спрашивали.

Comment: @Vadizar, ответ: "97%, что такого плагина не существует, т. к. он бесполезен и задействует редкоиспользуемую связку технологий".

Comment: я в ответе вижу рассуждения, а собственно сам ответ если и есть, то он находится между строк.

Comment: Буквально сейчас увидел и еще до конца не разобрался, но прошу помочь - postcss-list-selectors(A PostCSS plugin that exports all CSS selectors to JSON file.)

Comment: @walerij2406, из css в json - это не из php в css...

Comment: Смысл в том чтобы распарсить ДОМ и вывести все селекторы, вот и пытаюсь решить эту задачу